# How to increase geom_waffle plot's size?

Tags: r, ggplot2, waffle-chart

I am trying to make a waffle plot using `geom_waffle()` in R. Here is my code so far;

```
library(tidyverse)
library(waffle)
library(ggthemes)

haunted_places <- readr::read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rfordatascience/tidytuesday/master/data/2023/2023-10-10/haunted_places.csv')
haunted_places_top_5 <- haunted_places %>% 
  mutate(last_word = stringr::str_extract(location, "\\S+$"),
         last_word = str_to_title(last_word),
         last_word = case_when(last_word == "Rd." ~ "Road",
                               last_word == "Rd" ~ "Road",
                               last_word == "Streets" ~ "Street",
                               last_word == "Street)" ~ "Street", 
                               last_word == "St." ~ "Street", 
                               .default = as.character(last_word))) %>%
  group_by(last_word) %>%
  mutate(count = n(),
         percentage = count/10992,
         total_count = 10992) %>%
  select(last_word, count, total_count, percentage) %>%
  distinct() %>%
  arrange(desc(count))

haunted_places_top_5 <- haunted_places_top_5[1:5, ] 

ggplot(haunted_places_top_5, aes(fill = last_word, values = count)) +
  geom_waffle(color = "white", size = 0.25, na.rm = TRUE, nrows = 10) +
  facet_wrap(~last_word, nrow = 2) +
  theme_fivethirtyeight() +
  theme(panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major.y = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x = element_blank(),
        axis.text.y = element_blank(),
        legend.position = "none") +
  coord_fixed(ratio = 1)
```

And, this code returns the following plot;

[image]

My problem with this visualization is mainly due to small size of the tiles. Is there way or a trick that can help to customize the size of facetted panels so that they can be seen better by the audience? Thank you for your kind attention beforehand.

Comment: have your tried changing `facet_wrap(~last_word, nrow = 2)` to `facet_wrap(~last_word, nrow = 5)` to allow each waffle to span the entire output?  Also consider that R's plot scale is related to the output device - making the window bigger will make the plot (but not text) bigger.

Comment: Thanks for your comment however it just does not increase the size of tiles. In other words, what I would like to do is to be able to customize the squares' sizes (I am referring to the squares in waffle plot). I am concerned that this feature might not be available indeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A feasible approach involves scaling down the count values by dividing them by 10. This adjustment effectively reduces the count values, resulting in each tile of the waffle plot representing 10 units, rather than just one. Subsequently, this change can be clearly annotated on the plot for clarity.

```
plot <- ggplot(haunted_places_top_5, aes(fill = last_word, values = count/10)) +  # Scale down the count
  geom_waffle(color = "white", size = 0.25, na.rm = TRUE, nrows = 5) +
  facet_wrap(~last_word, nrow = 2) +
  theme_fivethirtyeight() +
  theme(panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major.y = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x = element_blank(),
        axis.text.y = element_blank(),
        legend.position = "none") +
  coord_fixed(ratio = 1) +
  annotate("text", x = Inf, y = Inf, label = "Each tile represents 10 units", 
           hjust = 1.1, vjust = 1.1, size = 3, color = "black")  # Add annotation
plot
```

[image]

Comment: While it is a working approach, I think there should be a feature that will allow to arrange the size of squares such as size argument in geom_point or so. However, thank you for your kind suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

A second option, if you choose not to divide by 10, is to just adjust both the rows and size command.

```
ggplot(haunted_places_top_5, aes(fill = last_word, values = count)) +
  geom_waffle(color = "white", size = 0.0001, na.rm = TRUE, nrows = 10) +  # Adjusted size here
  facet_wrap(~last_word, nrow = 5) +
  theme_fivethirtyeight() +
  theme(panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major.y = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x = element_blank(),
        axis.text.y = element_blank(),
        legend.position = "none") +
  coord_fixed(ratio = 1)
```

[image]

Interestingly, the smaller you go with the size, the larger the points get.

Comment: I see that this might also help but I am more into customizing the square size. And, also I might want to have 2 rows, this approach does a little bit limit the plot's layout, which I do not want to have. Thank you for your response though.